# Java abstract variable (superclass use subclass's String)

Tags: java, string, abstract, superclass

I have an `abstract class` Loader:

```
public abstract class Loader
{
    private String EXTENSION = ".xxx";
    private String dir;

    public abstract Object load(String file);
    public abstract List<?> loadList(String file, int number);

    public Loader(String dir)
    {
        this.dir = dir.replace("\\", "/") + "/";;
    }

    public String formatName(String name) 
    {
        return dir + name + EXTENSION;
    }
}
```

Its subclasses should be able to change the EXTENSION

```
public class MidiLoader extends Loader
{
    private String EXTENSION = ".mid";

    public MidiLoader(String dir)
    {
        super(dir);
    }

    public MidiLoader()
    {
        super(Constants.SOUNDDIR);
    }

    @Override
    public Sequence load(String file)
    {
        blah
    }

    public List<Sequence> loadList(String file, int number)
    {
        blah
    }

}
```

The EXTENSION ".mid" should be used by `Loader`'s `formatName` function. How do I get it to do this (without duplicating code)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a constructor

```
protected Loader(String dir, String ext)
```

This way the extension is determining by the sub-class.

BTW making a constructor for an abstract class `public` could be confusing as it cannot be used publicly.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this method, but I suppose it will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot override properties only methods. To follow a better OOP model you should use encapsulation and provide a getter and setter for EXTENSION. Put something like this in your Loader class:

```
 private String extension = ".xxx"

 public void setExtension(String extension) {
     this.extension = extension;
 }

 public String getExtension() {
     return this.extension;
 }


public String formatName(String name) {
    return dir + name + getExtension();
}
```

It is preferred to use a lowercase name for extension unless the property is actually a constant. You can then also add a few constructors to Loader.

```
// Previous without using an explict extension
public Loader(String dir) {
  ...
}

public Loader(String dir, String extension)
{
   this(dir); // call the default constructor
   this.extension = extension;
}
```

Then inside of MidiLoader constructor you could call call `super(dir,extension)`

Alternatively, you can ignore the constructors and the setter and just define getExtension() in every subclass. If you went that route it would be best to make getExtension abstract.

So Loader would have the following defined:

`public abstract String getExtension();`

Abstract methods must be implemented by subclasses and you cannot instantiate the abstract class itself. This means that MidiLoader would be forced to provide a method called getExtension() that returns a String and formatName would always work (using my augmented formatName method).

Comment: The upper case name was a leftover from when it was a constant. I tried changing around the modifiers to see if I could get it to work, but forgot to change case.